# Same CSS, different outcomes for <a> and <button>

Tags: html, css, button

I have a table that serves as the header of my page which contains 2 buttons.

By using only an < a href=""> tag for the add button, applying the same css styles to both buttons yielded different results.

My idea of fixing this was to wrap < button > tags in < a > tags so that
the css styling would be the same, but the add button would still behave as a clickable link.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="title"><h1>Product List</h1></td> 
      
      <td class="add-product-btn">
        <a href="https://google.com"><button>ADD</button></a>
      </td>

      <td class="delete-product-btn">
        <button> MASS DELETE </button>
      </td>

  </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: Which HTML documentation have you been reading that suggests placing a `<button>` inside an `<a>`? Use `<a>` _OR_ a `<button type="button">` with Javascript.

Comment: @brombeer as is said in another comment simply using the a tag doesn't work either. the <button> is used for css. Although the <button type="button"> for the delete button is redundant in my case.

Comment: I doubt that placing `<a href="https://google.com">ADD</a>` inside a `<td>` doesn't work, you must have done something wrong then. Take a look at the source code and make sure your HTML code is valid. _What_ exactly doesn't work? You can use CSS to style the `<a>` to look like a button if that's what you're after, `<button>` inside `<a>` is _NOT_ valid HTML

Comment: I copied your first code snippet and the `ADD` button is working, you might have made some mistake, check.

Comment: You can not nest `button` into `a`, or the other way around - that is invalid HTML, because they are both considered "interactive" elements. _"the <button> is used for css"_ - absolutely wrong decision making to begin with. If what you want to do _justifies_ being done with a link, then you _use_ a link - and format it to look however you want it using CSS.

Comment: @brombeer I made some progress. When done with `<a href="https://google.com">ADD</a>` it appears that the `<td class="title"><h1>Product List</h1></td>` is in front of the button and when I remove the heading I can click on the button.

Comment: @brombeer I dont know if it is allowed to ask questions like these in the comments but would `<a class="button" href="https://google.com">Click Me</a>` with the appropriate css be correct? I haven't been coding for a bit so my syntax is quite rusty.

Comment: That looks totally fine, yes.